# Jquery bluring manipulation

Tags: jquery

I have multiple div.Each div contains a text along with a "edit" button.On clicking the button a textbox will be append oo the div.My requirement is when i click anywhere accept the textbox,the textbox becomes invisible and and only div and "edit" button will be shown as it was.
Plese help me.

Comment: We are not magician, show some code please.

Answer (score 0):

Given the following HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div>
        <span>text</span><input class="edit" type="button" value="Edit" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>text</span><input class="edit" type="button" value="Edit" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>text</span><input class="edit" type="button" value="Edit" />
    </div>
</div>​
```

You can use javascript like this:

```
$(".edit").click(function() {
    var $new = "<input type='text' class='edittext'></input>";
    $(this).parent().append($new);
    $(this).parent().find(".edittext").focus();

});

$(".outer").on("focusout", ".edittext", function() {
    $(this).remove();
});​
```

Sample fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/johnkoer/mrJcp/9/